# How do I use Perl to push into an array of arrays?

Tags: perl

Below is a snippet of Perl code. I would like to loop through several queries with different regular expression (`$myo`) and for different operators (`$op`) and save the results to an array of arrays rather than one large `@result` array.

I.e., the array of results for `MYO[0-9]*$` would be an array for each operator `$results[0][0]`, `$results[0][1]` ... and for `MYO[0-9]*R$`, `$results[1][0]`, `$results[1][1]`.

Any ideas?

```
my @tech_ops =  ("AR","DB","GM","LW","MM","SA");
  my @results;

    for my $myo (qw(MYO[0-9]*$ MYO[0-9]*R$ MYO[0-9]*T$ MYO[0-9]*U$)) {
      foreach $op (@tech_ops)
        {
           $sth->execute($myo, $date_stop, $date_start,$op) 
         or die "Couldn't execute query for $myo: " . $sth->errstr;
           push @results, $sth->fetchrow_array;
         }
    }
```

Comment: I'm *guessing* that your SQL is only returning one column; if not, do you really want an array of arrays of arrays?

Comment: The array of array idea was to make it easier to populate the results into a latex table using a for loop. Probably not the most efficient solution but the first one i came up with

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
my @tech_ops =  ("AR","DB","GM","LW","MM","SA");
my @results;

for my $myo (qw(MYO[0-9]*$ MYO[0-9]*R$ MYO[0-9]*T$ MYO[0-9]*U$)) {
    my @myo_results;
    foreach $op (@tech_ops) {
        $sth->execute($myo, $date_stop, $date_start,$op) 
            or die "Couldn't execute query for $myo: " . $sth->errstr;
        push @myo_results, $sth->fetchrow_array;
    }
    push @results, \@myo_results;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `fetchall_arrayref` method instead of the `fetchrow_array` method.

So just replace this line:

```
push @results, $sth->fetchrow_array;
```

With this line:

```
push @results, $sth->fetchall_arrayref;
```

[Here is the documentation for all the DBI statement handler methods.](http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.623/DBI.pm#Statement_Handle_Methods)

Answer (score 0):

You could just use an array reference:

```
my $ref;
for my $i (1..10) {
   for my $j (1..10) {
        push @{$ref->[$i]}, $j;
    }
}
```

That will do it.

EDIT: This will create a reference to a 10x10 matrix.